# What is the most suitable classical decomposition model for the time-series graph?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, decomposition, economics

To decompose time series data using the classical decomposition method, we have additive as well as multiplicative model. What is the most suitable decomposition model to be used to decompose the time series data based on the given graph that can be seen in the link given below? Since I am new here, I cannot upload a picture of the time-series graph here.

https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/43518/what-is-the-most-suitable-decomposition-model-for-the-given-time-series-data

Comment: Since this is a cross-post, either wait for an answer to the original or flag the original for migration here.  (That will bring the image along with it.)